# Помогите решить проблему с открытием файла написанным на Visual Studio на Python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте я не давно начал программировать и написал калькулятор
у меня не получилось его открыть как готовый калькулятор что бы на нем можно было считать
у меня открывается как code из Visual Studio который я так написал
через что мне открыть code который я написал в Visual Studio так что бы открылся сам калькулятор
Так же если я скопирую то что я написал в Visual Studio в открою Python то калькулятор будет работать в консоли Python

Comment: А вот до того, как написать калькулятор, вы попробовали написать и запустить программу с единственной строкой кода: `print("abc")`? Получилось?

Comment: да, я пробовал но он сохраняется как текстовый фаил в котором написано print ("adc")

Comment: Добавте больше информации в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1254726/edit).  И поправте текст вопроса, в нём нет ни одного знака препинания включая заголовок. Набор слов, из которого непонятно, что вы пытаеетесь сделать.

Comment: Я написал калькулятор на Visual Studio Code (Python), затем я сохраняю
калькулятор. Как мне запустить сохраненный калькулятор? Если при открытии калькулятора, открывается code который я написал, а не готовый калькулятор, что в таких случаях делать? Через что мне открыть написанный code, что бы открылся калькулятор

Comment: В консоли: python calc.py

Comment: Вы пробовали пользоваться знаками препинания? Запятыми там, точками?Текст вашего вопроса без слёз читать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего файлы с расширением py ассоциированы с приложением Visual Studio, поэтому при запуске файлов python открывается именно он.
А вообще python интерпретируемый язык, т.е. для запуска написанных приложений нужен интерпретатор.
Можно запускать через python файл.py